# Finding The Biggest Key In A Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

### General:

I need help finding a way in python to get the max `N` items in a multi-dimensional python dictionary. For example:

```
 things = {
          "car": { "weight": 100 },
          "apple": { "weight": 1 },
          "spanner": { "weight": 10 } 
          }
```

In this case, I would want to find the 2 highest-weighted items in the dictionary, specifically the keys of these items. So in this case, it should return `["car", "spanner"]`

### *Actual Problem*:

*Note: This is my first attempt at a genetic algorithm, so I might not be doing it correctly. At all.*

As I am British, I am searching for the best cup of tea I can imagine, so I am writing a python program that generates 10 random cups of tea, then uses natural selection to find the top 5 in that ten and so on.

A cup of tea is modelled as a python dictionary, with 5 keys:

```
{
 "brew_time": Some Number,
 "milk": Some Number,
 "sweeteners": Some Number,
 "fitness": Some Number (This is what I'm interested in),
 "name": Some randomly generated name (Doesn't really matter)
}
```

A cup of tea my program will spit out will look something like this:

```
{'brew_time': 2.0, 'milk': 0.5, 'sweeteners': 3.0, 'name': 'bold cup', 'fitness': 0}
```

It then generates 10 cups of tea, stored in the `teas` variable. This is an example of an output of that:

```
{0: {'brew_time': 2.0, 'milk': 0.4, 'sweeteners': 1.0, 'name': 'unafraid brew', 'fitness': 0}, 1: {'brew_time': 3.0, 'milk': 0.5, 'sweeteners': 3.0, 'name': 'fire-eating blend', 'fitness': 0}, 2: {'brew_time': 2.0, 'milk': 0.6, 'sweeteners': 2.0, 'name': 'fearless drink', 'fitness': 0}, 3: {'brew_time': 2.0, 'milk': 0.9, 'sweeteners': 3.0, 'name': 'fire-eating blend', 'fitness': 0}, 4: {'brew_time': 2.0, 'milk': 0.8, 'sweeteners': 2.0, 'name': 'fire-eating cuppa', 'fitness': 0}, 5: {'brew_time': 3.0, 'milk': 0.3, 'sweeteners': 1.0, 'name': 'fire-eating drink', 'fitness': 0}, 6: {'brew_time': 4.0, 'milk': 0.7, 'sweeteners': 2.0, 'name': 'dauntless medley', 'fitness': 0}, 7: {'brew_time': 3.0, 'milk': 0.3, 'sweeteners': 2.0, 'name': 'dauntless cuppa', 'fitness': 0}, 8: {'brew_time': 3.0, 'milk': 0.9, 'sweeteners': 2.0, 'name': 'epic drink', 'fitness': 0}, 9: {'brew_time': 2.0, 'milk': 0.4, 'sweeteners': 2.0, 'name': 'gusty drink', 'fitness': 0}}
```

I'm now trying to code a function called `selection()` that will remove the 5 least fit teas from the dictionary. (The fitness of a tea is set by me, using the `rank_tea()` function, which takes an array and sets all the teas fitnesses, which is a number between 0 - 1 that represents the quality of the tea)

This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't work:

```
def selection():
    teaCopy = teas.copy()
    fitnesses = []
    for i in range(0, len(teaCopy)):
        fitnesses.append(teas[i]["fitness"])

    print(fitnesses)

    max_fitnesses_indicies = sorted(range(len(fitnesses)), key=lambda x: fitnesses[x])
    print(max_fitnesses_indicies)

    len_array = []
    print(len_array)
    for i in range(0, len(teas)):
        len_array.append(i)

    to_be_del = list( set(max_fitnesses_indicies) - set(len_array) )
    print(to_be_del)
```

[This is the full code.](https://gist.github.com/ollybritton/3248701a2dcc6280f19111c887164b5c) Sorry for the length of the question, I just didn't want to miss anything.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What output are you getting and what does not work?

Comment: You 'Actual Problem' does not seem to be related to the original question and only confuses the readers. I suggest that you construct a minimal viable example.

Comment: StackOverflow is mainly for fixing errors. Maybe you are looking for Code Review instead? Also, genetic algorithms seem like an overkill for this particular problem since you can just find the largest value in a single pass, pop it, and do one more pass to find the next largest. Or more generally, it's a sorting a dictionary problem.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
>>> sorted(things.keys(),key=lambda x:things[x]['weight'],reverse=True)
['car', 'spanner', 'apple']
```

To obtain a list of items sorted by their weight (here in reversed order such that the more heavy things are sorted first). So if you call:

```
>>> sorted(things.keys(),key=lambda x:things[x]['weight'],reverse=True)[:2]
['car', 'spanner']
```

you get the two heaviest. But this will **run in *O(n log n)***. In case the **number of values *k* you wish to obtain is small** (compared to the total number). You can use `heapq`:

```
from heapq import nlargest

result = nlargest(k,things.keys(),key=lambda x:things[x]['weight'])
```

which will - as far as I know - **run in *O(n log k)*** (*k* the numbers of items you want to pick).

Comment: And then just cut off the list?

Comment: @OllyBritton: the second code fragment already cuts of the list with `[0:2]`. The last one *never* generates more values than `k` (the first argument) so here you safe some computational effort.

Comment: `[key for key, value in sorted(things.items(), key=lambda key, value: value['weight'], reverse=True)]` would be faster as there's no dictionary lookup.

Comment: @PeterWood: I don't know if that is true. You save on the lookup but you have additional tuple packing/unpacking, and an additional list comprehension. I'm not convinced one will significantly outperform the other one.

Comment: @PeterWood: if I recall correctly Python also has a small *flyweight* cache for tuples so it will first check if a certain tuple already exists which is also a lookup (but a one hardwired in the interpreter, so faster). Nevertheless it will take *some* time.

Comment: @PeterWood As per `%timeit`, Willem's expression runs ~20% faster on a 100-item list than yours.